# Internal Server Error (500) AWS Elasticbeanstalk deployed flask app

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed various versions of the app previously with no errors. 
However, I had to make some modifications on two tables in my AWS RDS running PostgreSQL. `alter table NAME alter column NAME type date using to_date(...)`
I've done that directly on the AWS RDS and modified SQLAlchemy column accordingly. `date = Column(Date)`
Any API call that sends queries these two tables returns Internal Server Error - In the meantime, there are no errors in deploying this version of the app and moreover from my python interpreter running any SQLAlchemy code that queries any of these two tables always returns what's expected.

I have tried several ways to fix this. The only one that worked is to remove the line `date = Column(Date)` from SQLAlchemy setup file - Then there was no 500 on any API call but of course that doesn't help as I need that column!

Any help on this will be highly appreciated really...

Comment: @reptilicus... You mean from the sever? There are no deployment errors and there are no errors when running python code that queries the database...

Comment: I have found this notice in `eb logs`... [Thu Oct 22 12:57:56.343259 2015] [core:notice] [pid 30224] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND' - Does it have to do with anything I am suffering from?

Comment: put it in debug mode DEGUG=True, should get full traceback with a 500 error

Comment: @reptilicus... I've got `application.run(debug=True)` but there isn't a full traceback that could really help! It just says Internal Server Error and contact the website administrator...

Comment: It must be something related to AWS elastic beanstalk because the code works fine locally... So the mapping between SQLAlchemy Date datatype and PostgreSQL DATE is okay...

Comment: `def as_dict(self): return {column.name: getattr(self, column.name) for column in self.__table__.columns}` - It was this line here! I was in a hurry to test JSON and used this instead of `jsonify`... So after altering the column to SQLAlchemy Date object that is timedate.date, the dictionary above was the one that caused the error... :)